# How to find solutions to a linear Diophantine equation restricted to given intervals of x and y?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

For example: find all $x$, $y$ satisfying $10x + 20y = 300$ and $-10 < x < 10 ,  0 < y < 20$. I wanted to write a program for this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dividing by $$10$$ we get $$x=30-2y$$ so we obtain
$$-10<30-2y<10$$ and from here $$10<y<20$$
These are the solutions $$(x=-8\land y=19)\lor (x=-6\land y=18)\lor (x=-4\land y=17)\lor (x=-2\land
   y=16)\lor (x=0\land y=15)\lor (x=2\land y=14)\lor (x=4\land y=13)\lor
   (x=6\land y=12)\lor (x=8\land y=11)$$